# How to validate in Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am new to jQuery. I have a text field and I want to validate this field so that it only takes character and alphanumeric values, however if you put in a numeric value it will show a message. How should I implement this?

Comment: What you already tried?

Comment: http://jqueryvalidation.org/ see this will help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#textfieldid').on('change', function(event) {
    var text = $('#textfieldid').text();
    //some validation code here
});
```

By the way, JQuery is a javascript library, not Java (which you have tagged).

Answer (score 0):

Using regex, validations can be done.

```
var password = document.getElementB;
var letter = /[a-zA-Z]/; 
var number = /[0-9]/;
if(number.test(password) && letter.test(password)){
    //success
}else{
    //error
}
```

Here password is the value which is returned from the field